# Testing DLL in VC++ cannot step into a function

Tags: c++, windows, dll

I made a DLL in VC++ using Visual Studio 2008 professional and I'm trying to test(debug) it!
So I made another project but when I try to make a step into a class I made it just steps forward.

I also try click on the class and go to the definition (where it appear Cannot Load Symbol)

I try in tool>>options>>Debuging>>symbols to add the path to the .pdb file

My code as the dll declaration

```
 #pragma once

 __declspec(dllexport) long sdk_init();
 //__declspec(dllexport) long sdk_release();

 __declspec(dllexport) long sdk_connect(long handle);
 __declspec(dllexport) long sdk_getObjectList(long handle);
 //__declspec(dllexport) long sdk_disconnect(long handle);

 __declspec(dllexport) long sdk_playStream(long handle, int idx);
 __declspec(dllexport) long sdk_stopStream(long handle, int idx);
```

and then the implemantetion for instance ~

```
long sdk_init(){
    CDataManager* m_DataManager = new CDataManager();
    int i = m_DataManager->InitXns();
    if(i == 0){
        return 0;
    }
    return (long) m_DataManager;
}
```

The class I can't step into is the CDataManager, that is a class created by me.
    #include

```
using namespace std;
#include <list>

class CDataManager : 
    public IDeviceSink, 
    public IMediaSink  
{
    public:
        int InitXns(void);
        int Connect(int nDeviceId);
        int GetObjectList(void);
        int RequestLiveStream(int videoSource);
        int StopLiveStream(int videoSource);
    private:
        int  m_bInitXns;
        int login;
        //store in list?
        XNS_DEVICE2 m_sDevice;
        //safe store?
        XNS_OBJECT *m_pObject;
        XNS_OBJECT *m_pVideoSource;
    public:
        CDataManager();
        virtual ~CDataManager();
        int SetWnd(HWND hWnd);
        long OnResponse(XNS_REQUEST* pReq);
        long OnEvent(XNS_EVENT* pEvent);
        long OnVideo(UINT nMID, XNS_VIDEO_HEADER* pVideo);
        long OnAudio(UINT nMID, XNS_AUDIO_HEADER* pAudio);
```

Comment: Where does C# come into this?

Comment: Sorry for using the wrong flag, this is all in C++ environment

Comment: @crashmsrt do you have some constructive idea?

Comment: Do you have these both in a single solution, and have them outputting to the same folder? If not, are you copying the debug DLL and pdb files into the output folder of the other project?

Comment: yes I have the dll and the "Test DLL project" in separated solutions,
In Test DLL project
I made the following configurations
C++ -> add path to DLL headers.
Linker path to .lib and the lib include

then I put the dll and the pdb in the folder.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix my problem:
I changed the "Debugger Type" to "Mixed" in configuration properties>>debugging of my test solution

Anyhow, I don't understand the why I need to do that, if someone was an explanation please post.